# Mail Add-in OnSend event time limit in OWA

Tags: office-js, office-addins

Is there a limit on how long you can wait before completing the OnSend event using the event.completed method in a Mail Add-in in OWA?

It appears that if you do not issue the event.completed method within 5 minutes then the event.completed call is ignored and the OnSend event is never completed. The "Sending" message with the spinner stays forever and OWA stops working. The browser needs to be refreshed to reload OWA in order to get OWA working again.

I cannot find any reference to time limits in the documentation for the OnSend event.

In our case we are opening up a dialog for the user during the OnSend event with options for the user that can stop or allow the send. The user can choose to have this dialog open for as as long as they want. So having a period of more than 5 minutes from the OnSend event opening the dialog and user then making a selection is a valid scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We do know about this, it's an unintended bug and we already have a fix in the works. The expected experience would be that after 5 minute timeout threshold is reached the dialog is closed and the mail is not sent. The user interface should not be impacted by this functionality. The timeout value is not configurable, the 5-minute timeout applies to all Execute Function and On Send add-in commands.

Michael